# Convert http post variables to an anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a ashx page setup to handle incoming http posts from a service.

And I'd like to know if there's a better way to populate my anonymous type rather than doing it manually.  for example.

```
public class myclass
{
    [key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
}
```

then on my ashx page

```
myclass mc = new myclass();

mc.field1 = context.Request.Form[field1];
mc.field2 = context.Request.Form[field2];
```

isn't there just a way to cast or convert it to my type?

```
myclass mc = new myclass();
mc = context.Request.Form;
```

Comment: In this context I understand better as equal to less code.

Comment: Is this Web Forms? MVC? Web API?

Comment: @mason This is webforms. the file getting the http post data is an ashx file handler.

Comment: @Dalorzo less code or a more generic way of handling possibly some 30+ http post variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "better" you mean a one liner where performance is not your number one concern, sure you can do this in Reflection by filtering out potential properties based on the keys in your request context.

```
mc.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where (x => context.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(x.Name)).ToList()
    .ForEach(x => 
        x.SetValue(mc, Convert.ChangeType(context.Request.Form[x.Name], x.PropertyType)));
```

That said, is this resilient to null checking / type checking?  Nope.  Is it performant?  Not at all. Is it readable?  I confused myself three times just writing it.  So while it is possible to do something like this, that doesn't mean it's better.  Sometimes pulling out each property manually is the best way to do it.

Comment: @Prescient Final edit.  AllKeys can be checked instead of needing to pull out each key with `.Select()`

Comment: Nice. so far visual studio doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Also, You can use this extension methods. (I didn't implement `null` checks or type checks)

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static void SetValue(this object self, string name, object value)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = self.GetType().GetProperty(name);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(self, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
        public static void SetValues(this object self, NameValueCollection nameValues) {

            foreach (var item in nameValues.AllKeys)
            {
                SetValue(self, item, nameValues[item]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way:

```
  myclass mc = new myclass();
  mc.SetValues(Request.Form);
```